# Electronic band structure

Tags: electronic-band-theory

I want to know why the bands like valence or conduction splits up into two parts as shown in this diagram. why the energy gaps exist with in these bands? As  you can see in this diagram that their is an energy gap with in conduction as well as valence band. what  are their physical significance?

[image: band structure diagram]

Comment: Why they split up? Because of difference in energy.

Comment: This is not true for metals though as the conduction and valence band overlap.

Comment: Difference of energy between what? it's a semiconductor.

Comment: You did not mention semiconductors before.

Comment: I'm not talking about the energy gap between conduction and valence band. As you can see there is a an energy gap with in conduction band.

Comment: @MemoonaMehmood I suspect that, when  you are referring  to "an energy gap in conduction band" you are meaning something different with respect to what was meant by some of the answers. Probably it would help a lot if you could put some symbol on the bands of the picture, in order to make clear which band you are speaking about.

Comment: To understand the band structure you can take a look at the 1-dimensional single-electron Penney-Kronig model (1 electron in a periodic 1D potential), Original 1931 paper: https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1931.0019. See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760517/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the bands depends on how the atomic orbitals interact with their neighbors in the crystal as a function of wavevector $k$ - where $k$ represents a phase shift from atom to atom.  When the orbitals of nearest neighbors overlap a small change of phase will change the nature of the overlap and, thus, of the energy level.  In many familiar semiconductors the lowest conduction and highest valence bands correspond to the anti-bonding and bonding levels of $sp^3$ hybridized orbitals in the diamond or zinc-blende structure.  In such cases the gap between bonding and anti-bonding is the band gap which makes the crystal a semiconductor.  Orbitals involved in bonding tend to have large overlap and a strong dependence of energy on $k$.

Now, the answer to your question:

However, there are other atomic orbitals as well.  For example, in silicon there are unfilled $3d$ levels which lie higher up in energy.  The $d$ orbitals do not overlap with neighbors as much as $s$ and $p$ orbitals tend to, and they result in very flat bands.  Flat bands are less likely to overlap with other bands in energy and can create additional gaps in the band structure.

Deeper levels that are lower in energy and filled also tend to have lower principal quantum number, $n$, and are thus more deeply bound in the atoms and thus less liklely to overlap with one another and also result in flat bands lying deep in the valence structure - possibly also creating additional gaps there.

Most semiconductors physicists study just the lowest few conduction bands and the highest few valence bands because it is the filling and unfilling of these levels near the main band gap that determine the properties of fabricated devices like transistors.  Studying the more distant bands is less common.

Comment: Is their any physical significance of these gaps?

Comment: Yes, these gaps represent the gaps between energy levels of the basis atoms.  So, for example, if silicon has a gap in the conduction band it might originate in the gap between $4s$ and $3d$ levels in the silicon atom itself.  I haven't checked any given band structure - but I think you see what I mean?  Similarly a gap in the valence structure might represent the difference between the $n=2$ and $n=3$ levels in the silicon atom.

Comment: Okay, thankyou for your answer.

Comment: @MemoonaMehmood If this answers your question, then accept the answer by clicking the tick below it.

Answer (score 0):

The **band** get its name because it encompasses the range of different energy levels which an electron can take. As long as their energy is high enough, they will lie inside the conduction band.

As for gap, that is because energy can not take continuous values (Quantized) and that is why a gap exists between electrons that lie inside the conduction band.

Comment: I understand that it  is quantized but as in the diagram it's quite a large energy gap. any Reason behind it?

Comment: This is incorrect: "many electrons with different energy levels ". Bands are usually single electron orbitals. The energy is varying with momentum.

Comment: @my2cts Is the correct edit correct?

Comment: @harshit54 That is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that electron orbitals are quantised. In a crystal an electron can have linear momentum, $\hbar \vec k$. This is described by crystal orbital, which are basically linear combinations of atomic orbitals at crystal site $\vec r_i$ with coefficients $e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r_i}$. The energy of such orbitals depends on the value of $\vec k$ which is why the curves are not horizontal and straight but go up and down as a function of $\vec k$ forming bands. If the variation of energy with $\vec k$ or band width is large enough, crystal bands overlap. If not there is a gap. The other important parameter is on-site repulsion. If this is large then different bands are pushed apart. It is the ration of bandwidth to on-site repulsion that  in the simple Hubbard model determines whether a crystal behaves like a metal or like a semiconductor / insulator.

Comment: Okay you are trying to say that it deals with the orientation of the orbitals?

Comment: We can say that these are the orbitals energy gaps?

Comment: I say that that crystal orbital energy varies with crystal momentum, giving bands instead of levels and that there may be crystal orbital energy gaps. Discrete energy states occur everywhere in quantum systems. In this case the term gap is used as the discrete levels vary with momentum.