# Applications of the Kronig-Penney Model

Tags: potential, semiconductor-physics

I would like to know some applications of the Kronig-Penney Model and what parameters (effective mass, width...) are interesting to change in order to study those applications.

Comment: Original paper: "Quantum mechanics of electrons in crystal lattices" by Kronig & Penney (1931), https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1931.0019. Their point is to use a simplified periodic potential for a single electron in a 1D crystal to get a better idea of the earlier work of Bloch on band structure. See also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice